# Dedupe a list of dicts where the match criteria is multiple key value pairs being identical

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, duplicates

For the given sample input list, I want to dedupe the dicts based on the values of the keys `code`, `tc`, `signal`, and `in_force` all matching.

###### sample input:

```
signals = [
    None,
    None,
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 1, 'target': 0},
    {'code': 'lr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 2, 'target': 1},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 1, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 3, 'target': 2},
    None,
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '1-2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 4, 'target': 3},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': False, 'trigger': 5, 'target': 4},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 6, 'target': 5},
    None,
    {'code': 'lr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 7, 'target': 6},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 1, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 8, 'target': 7},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '1-2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 9, 'target': 8},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': False, 'trigger': 0, 'target': 9},
]
```

###### expected/desired output:

```
[
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 1, 'target': 0},
    {'code': 'lr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 2, 'target': 1},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 1, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 3, 'target': 2},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '1-2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 4, 'target': 3},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': False, 'trigger': 5, 'target': 4},
]
```

The order of the list does not need to be preserved, and whether it returns the 1st or nth matching dict in the list does not matter.

I could make a very verbose version of this reference code that creates each list of matching key/values, but I feel like there's got to be a better way.

```
new_list = []
for position, signal in enumerate(signals):
    if type(signal) == dict:
            if {
                key: value
                for key, value in signal.items()
                if signal["code"] == "sr"
                and signal["tc"] == 0
                and signal["signal"] == "2U-2D"
                and signal["in_force"] == True
            }:
                new_list.append(signal)
```

Comment: Yes.  It’s very close to the answer @nickie provided.  My keyword search for previous questions could have been better; I probably would have caught this answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this, with only Python's standard library:

```
result = []
seen = set()
for s in signals:
  if not isinstance(s, dict): continue
  signature = (s['code'], s['tc'], s['signal'], s['in_force'])
  if signature in seen: continue
  seen.add(signature)
  result.append(s)
```

Comment: cheers! hope we can learn from each other!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that is wanted but `pandas` could be come in quite handy here. Also if you have some other tasks to do with the data, a dataframe is a convenient way to do it.

```py
import pandas as pd
# filter None to only have a list of dicts, then create a df with it
df = pd.DataFrame(filter(None,signals)) 

out = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['code', 'tc', 'signal', 'in_force'], keep='first')

out.to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
[{'code': 'sr',
  'tc': 0,
  'signal': '2U-2D',
  'in_force': True,
  'trigger': 1,
  'target': 0},
 {'code': 'lr',
  'tc': 0,
  'signal': '2U-2D',
  'in_force': True,
  'trigger': 2,
  'target': 1},
 {'code': 'sr',
  'tc': 1,
  'signal': '2U-2D',
  'in_force': True,
  'trigger': 3,
  'target': 2},
 {'code': 'sr',
  'tc': 0,
  'signal': '1-2U-2D',
  'in_force': True,
  'trigger': 4,
  'target': 3},
 {'code': 'sr',
  'tc': 0,
  'signal': '2U-2D',
  'in_force': False,
  'trigger': 5,
  'target': 4}]
```

Comment: I am using pandas in a different part of this application, so I could certainly have used that, thank you for the answer.  I appreciate the answer provided by @nickie as it uses the standard library, so I've selected theirs as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that fits into 1 line of code and does not use any external libraries.

To begin with, let's filter out all None values:

```
signals = filter(lambda x: not x is None, signals)
```

or

```
signals = [signal for signal in signals if not signal is None]
```

Now let's create a dict where keys will be string `repr` representations of `code`, `tc`, `signal`, and `in_force` values of our input dicts (this should work until there's only simple types of values) and the values will be the complete dicts (consistent of all keys). As a dict may not contain several equal keys, all the duplications will be gone:

```
filter_dict = {repr([signal[key] for key in ('code', 'tc', 'signal', 'in_force')]): signal for signal in signals}
```

Here's what I've got at this point:

```
{
    "['sr', 0, '2U-2D', True]": {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 6, 'target': 5},
    "['lr', 0, '2U-2D', True]": {'code': 'lr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 7, 'target': 6},
    "['sr', 1, '2U-2D', True]": {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 1, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 8, 'target': 7},
    "['sr', 0, '1-2U-2D', True]": {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '1-2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 9, 'target': 8},
    "['sr', 0, '2U-2D', False]": {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': False, 'trigger': 0, 'target': 9}
}
```

Now let's just take the values of that dict, and its all done!:

```
result = list(filter_dict.values())
```

All these steps may be joined into 1 line of code:

```
result = list({repr([signal[key] for key in ('code', 'tc', 'signal', 'in_force')]): signal for signal in signals if not signal is None}.values()) # speed: 9.7e-6 seconds per iteration
```

Final result:

```
[
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 6, 'target': 5},
    {'code': 'lr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 7, 'target': 6},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 1, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 8, 'target': 7},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '1-2U-2D', 'in_force': True, 'trigger': 9, 'target': 8},
    {'code': 'sr', 'tc': 0, 'signal': '2U-2D', 'in_force': False, 'trigger': 0, 'target': 9}
]
```

May be my solution is not fastest (because I'm using strings) and it may not work with all possible classes that may be in the original dicts (because some classes may not convert into strings correctly by `repr` function). But at least it's very simple.

Update:

It turns out that `tuple` may be used instead of `repr` (see comments). This should be the best (also the fastest) solution:

```
result = list({tuple(signal[key] for key in ('code', 'tc', 'signal', 'in_force')): signal for signal in signals if not signal is None}.values()) # speed: 6.4e-6 seconds per iteration
```

Comment: It's not simple but it's not inherently slower and I'll definitely upvote such a one-liner. You don't need the `repr`, btw. The following is equivalent to my solution: `result = list({tuple(s[key] for key in ('code', 'tc', 'signal', 'in_force')): s for s in signals if isinstance(s, dict)}.values())`. Well done!

Comment: @nickie , it does not work like that. At first I also thought that tuples should be good solution, but as it turns out tuples does not work. 2 different tuple objects (even if they contain similar values) counts as different dict keys, so the duplicationes will remain. That's the reason why I used strings.

Comment: I think you're wrong in that. Otherwise, tuples would be pretty useless in Python. Try, e.g.
`d = {}; d[(1, 2, "haha")] = 1; d[(5-4, 8-6, "ha"+"ha")] = 2; print(d.values())`.

Comment: @nickie , yes, I was wrong. It turns out that I used `()` instead of `tuple()`. I thought that I will get tuples like that but I've got generators. That's the reason of my mistake. Your version works fine. Also I found another solution. It is to use `hash` manually. I will update my answer.

Comment: Using `hash` manually won't always work correctly, as there will be tuples with the same hash value. Improbable but possible. Just use the tuple as the dict's key.

Comment: @nickie , you are right again. Removing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
new_list = pd.Series([s for s in signals if isinstance(s, dict)])
keys = ['code', 'tc', 'signal', 'in_force']
idx = new_list.apply(lambda x: {x[k] for k in keys}).duplicated()
new_list = new_list[idx].tolist()
```